# .kaggle not found in C:/users/username/

Tags: kaggle

I installed kaggle using `pip install kagggle`.I created a new API token but, .kaggle is not found in the location :C:/users/username/. Where do I store kaggle.json?

Comment: If it doesn't exist, you will need to make it.